# Show that $E$ is the closure of $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The full problem is as follows:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$. Let $E$ be the set of all $p\in X$ for which there is a sequence $\left \{ p_n \right \}$ with $p_n \in A$ for each $n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(p_n) = p$.  Show that $E$ is the closure of $A$.

My thoughts:

To show that E is the closure of A, I have to show that E contains all limit points of A. But, the way the problem defines $E$, to me it is already said that the limits of arbitrary sequence $p_n$ reside in $E$! So what exactly is there left to prove here? Perhaps I am misunderstanding the goal of this exercise or reading it improperly.

Just need a hint to start. Thanks!

Comment: A limit point of $E$ is defined as a point such that for every $r>0$, $B(p,r) \cap E$ contains points of $E \setminus \{p\}$. Nothing with limits. This exercise actually shows why they're called "limit points": because they happen to be limits of sequences too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in E$, then by assumption $x$ is the limit of some sequence in $A$, so $A \cap U$ is nonempty for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$; so $E \subset$ the closure of $A$. If $x \in$ the closure of $A$, then $A \cap U$ is nonempty for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$. So for every integer $n \geq 1$ there is some $p_{n} \in A \cap B(x,n^{-1})$. Then $(p_{n})$ by construction is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$, so $x \in E$. We are done here.